# Video saved in temp folder works in AVPlayer on simulator but not on real device

Tags: avplayer, parse-ios-sdk

I am having a problem with `AVPlayer`, I'm using Parse SDK to store user files, and I want to fetch a movie file (.mp4) and display it using `AVPlayer`. There is a problem with using directly the Parse file url, so I'm trying a different approach:

```
// First, I load the file from the video url
// `name` is the file name fetched from Parse
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: videoURL) { data, response, error in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        do {
            // I will store locally the file to be read by AVPlayer afterwards
            let filepath = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
            try data?.write(to: filepath, options: .atomicWrite)
            // I create an AVPlayerItem from the local url
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: filepath as URL)
            let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)                        
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            self.viewController?.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                playerViewController.player?.play()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }                        
    }          
}.resume()
```

This works fine with the simulator, but I end up having no video playing when using a real device.

Any idea?

Thank you for your help